# Buildozer doesn't install hostpython3

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build an app with buildozer, and it gets stuck when downloading hostpython3. The last message is:
`[INFO]:    Downloading hostpython3 from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.1/Python-3.8.1.tgz`
and it never gets downloaded. I tried downloading it manually and placing it in `.../Python/kivy_sms/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/packages`, but it removes it and does the same thing. Is there a way to bypass this and download it manually?

Answer (score 0):

check other DIRs under `.../packages`, those downloaded ones should have an empty file starts with `".make"` `sth.`, besides the `.tgz` file. Mimic this should stop buildozer from downloading the file again.